# Syntax error in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am new to ArcGIS. I am trying to do a lot downscale the data using IDW tool in ArcGIS. I have one shapefile. In this shapefile, I have multiple columns. Each column corresponds to each year. I want to iterate through each year using IDW tool. I am using ArcPy for this. Unfortunately, I am getting an error at the end.

My code is following:

```
import arcpy
shp = "T:\\Samarth\\project\\prjairtemp.shp"
shp_field_name = [f.aliasName for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp, "Year_20*", "Double")]
prjairtemp = "T:\\Samarth\\project\\prjairtemp.shp"
test = "T:\\Samarth\\Studyarea\\test.shp"

for field in shp_field_name:
    try:
        if not field.required:
        IDWname = "T:\\Samarth\\IDW\\" + str(field.name) + ".tif"
        arcpy.Idw_3d(prjairtemp, field, IDWname, "10000", "2", "VARIABLE 12", "")
        clipIDW = "T:\\Samarth\\Clip_IDW\\" + str(field.name) + ".tif"
        arcpy.Clip_management(IDWname, "-1008952.43359909 3275056.34237466 553101.562858121 4949773.07466453", clipIDW, test, "", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
        final = "T:\\Samarth\\rastertopoint\\" + "airtemp" + str(field.name) + ".shp"
        arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(clipIDW, final, "Value")
        except:
            print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

I get the following error message.

```
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 10)
```

I tried running second code to see if changing the code might help. Same error message at the same line. Here is the second code.

```
import arcpy

try:
    shp = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\Seaicefrac\\projection\\prjseaicefrac.shp"
    shp_field_name = [f.aliasName for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp, "Year_20*", "Double")]

    prjairtemp = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\Seaicefrac\\projection\\prjseaicefrac.shp"

    test = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\studyarea_downscaled\Dump\\test.shp"

    for field in shp_field_name:
        IDWname = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\\Seaicefrac\\tiff\\IDW" + str(field.name) + ".tif"
        arcpy.Idw_3d(prjairtemp, field, IDWname, "10000", "2", "VARIABLE 12", "")
        clipIDW = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\\Seaicefrac\\tiff\\clip" + str(field.name) + ".tif"
        arcpy.Clip_management(IDWname, "-1008952.43359909 3275056.34237466 553101.562858121 4949773.07466453", clipIDW, test, "", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
        final = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\\Seaicefrac\\master\\seaicefrac" + str(field.name) + ".shp"
        arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(clipIDW, final, "Value")

except:
        print "Script failed to complete"
        print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
```

Here is the error message.

```
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 13)
```

Comment: Your title seems to assert ArcPy is at fault, not your formatting.

Comment: If you remove your try/except while testing and from the code you present here there is likely to be a more informative error message seen.

Comment: Hey PolyGeo, I tried that but than my result folder stays empty. Nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you Vince for your comment. I tried running the code with same format as Gob Tron but I get the same error.

Comment: @Samarth When you remove the `try`/`except`, what error messages do you get?  They should be more informative

Comment: @Samarth you have indentation problems in your both first and second examples. Use 4 spaces as indent for each level, put try and except on the same level and so on.

Answer (score 1):

By having a quick look at your code, the first thing I see is an indentation problem.

```
import arcpy

try:
  shp = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\Seaicefrac\\projection\\prjseaicefrac.shp"
  shp_field_name = [f.aliasName for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp, "Year_20*", "Double")]

  prjairtemp = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\Seaicefrac\\projection\\prjseaicefrac.shp"

  test = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\studyarea_downscaled\Dump\\test.shp"

  for field in shp_field_name:
      IDWname = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\\Seaicefrac\\tiff\\IDW" + str(field.name) + ".tif"
      arcpy.Idw_3d(prjairtemp, field, IDWname, "10000", "2", "VARIABLE 12", "")
      clipIDW = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\\Seaicefrac\\tiff\\clip" + str(field.name) + ".tif"
      arcpy.Clip_management(IDWname, "-1008952.43359909 3275056.34237466 553101.562858121 4949773.07466453", clipIDW, test, "", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
      final = "C:\\Users\\Lab-User\\Documents\\fourth_chapter_PC\\Summary_10km\\Seaicefrac\\master\\seaicefrac" + str(field.name) + ".shp"
      arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(clipIDW, final, "Value")

except:
  print "Script failed to complete"
  print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
```

Comment: I tried with your version too. Still the same error message.